# Writing full contents of Pandas dataframe to HTML table

Tags: python, html, pandas

I am embedding links in one column of a Pandas dataframe (table, below) and writing the dataframe to hmtl.

Links in the dataframe table are formatted as shown (indexing first link in table):

```
In: table.loc[0,'Links']
Out: u'<a href="http://xxx.xx.xxx.xxx/browser/I6.html">I6</a>'
```

If I view (rather than index a specific row) the dataframe (in notebook), the link text is truncated:

```
<a href="http://xxx.xx.xxx.xxx/browser/I6.html...
```

I write the dataframe to html:

```
table_1=table.to_html(classes='table',index=False,escape=False)
```

But, the truncated link (rather than the full text) is written to the html table:

```
 <td> <a href="http://xxx.xx.xxx.xxx/browser/I6.html...</td>\n
```

I probably need an additional parameter for to_html().

Look at the documentation now, but advice appreciated:

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_html.html

Thanks!

Comment: I've submitted a [pull request](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/9579) to pandas to make this kind of thing easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So there is probably a pandas-specific explanation, but you could also work around the problem by (a) replacing the links with a key value, (b) writing the html table string, and then (c) replacing the keys with the appropriate links.

For example, replace each link with a key, storing the keys in a dict:

```
map = {}
for i in df.index:
    counter = 0
    if df.ix[i]['Links'] in map:
        df.ix[i, 'Links'] = map[df.ix[i]['Links']]
    else:
        map[df.ix[i, 'Links']] = 'href' + str(counter)
        counter += 1
        df.ix[i, 'Links'] = map[df.ix[i]['Links']]
```

Write the table:

```
table_1 = df.to_html(classes='table',index=False,escape=False)
```

Re-write the links:

```
for key, value in map.iteritems():
    table_1 = table_1.replace(value, key)
```

Comment: Thanks, this should work. I ended up solving it in pandas by increasing the dataframe column width: pd.options.display.max_colwidth = 100