# Pandas to_html() truncates string contents

Tags: python, html, pandas

I have a Python Pandas `DataFrame` object containing textual data. My problem is, that when I use [`to_html()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_html.html) function, it truncates the strings in the output.

For example:

```py
import pandas
df = pandas.DataFrame({'text': ['Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.']})
print (df.to_html())
```

The output is truncated at `adapis...`

```
<table border="1" class="dataframe">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: right;">
      <th></th>
      <th>text</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>0</th>
      <td> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipis...</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

There is a related question on SO, but it uses placeholders and search/replace functionality to postprocess the HTML, which I would like to avoid:

- [Writing full contents of Pandas dataframe to HTML table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25070758/writing-full-contents-of-pandas-dataframe-to-html-table)

Is there a simpler solution to this problem? I could not find anything related from the [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_html.html).

Comment: How are you viewing the contents, is it through iPython? try this `pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', -1)` and then print the html, you should find that it displays the full text, this is nothing to do with truncation of the actual data just a display setting

Comment: @EdChum Yes, indeed I was looking at the HTML trough IPython, but also got same results in ordinary python terminal. But yes, set_option fixes that! In both the terminal and IPython. Did not know about that possibility before.

Comment: pandas tries to protect you from display reams of output that might kill lesser python environments, apart from obscure bugs I've not heard of it ever truncating the data

Comment: There is a list of them here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21293536/list-of-pandas-options/21293562#21293562 and the online docs: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/options.html

Answer (score 117, accepted):

What you are seeing is pandas truncating the output for display purposes only.

The default `max_colwidth` value is 50 which is what you are seeing.

You can set this value to whatever you desire or you can set it to -1 which effectively turns this off:

```
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', -1)
```

Although I would advise against this, it would be better to set it to something that can be displayed easily in your console or ipython.

A list of the options can be found here: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/options.html

Comment: ` "..." in df.to_html()` evaluates to `True`. It sure seems like `pandas` is truncating the output value, not just the display.

Comment: I have a very curious case, which I describe in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51260756/pandas-abbreviates-dictionary-in-cell where a cell value in an html table holds a dictionary. The dictionaries, which are not that big as this one are shown alright in other tables, but this particular very long dictionary gets abbreviated by dots and I can not make it show up. I experimented with pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 1000), no luck. Any suggestions for this or even an answer to my question?

Comment: Is this still the way to do this in v 0.24?

Comment: @JasonStrimpel yes I believe so

Comment: How can I change the length of the string displayed only for one column of the dataframe and not all of the columns?

Comment: @Superdooperhero you can't, the display options affect all columns or rows

Comment: As of v1.0.1 [`pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew/v1.0.1.html#deprecations) should be used.

Answer (score 20):

it seems that `pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', -1)` is indeed the only option. To prevent irreversible global changes of how dataframes are presented in the console, you may save the previous setting in a variable and restore it immediately after the usage, as follows:

```
    old_width = pd.get_option('display.max_colwidth')
    pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', -1)
    open('some_file.html', 'w').write(some_data.to_html())
    pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', old_width)
```

Comment: There is a much simpler solution how to set temporary option: `with pd.option_context('display.max_colwidth', -1): output_html = df.to_html()`