# Pandas html: Don't truncate long values

Tags: python, pandas

I understand that pandas does cut-off long elements. However, why does it do that in the html output?

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['url'], index=[0])
df['url'] = 'd12dn1928d1n298dn18d9n219d8n18n118219d8n21e12903e21kj9012j9301j2391023j209d12dn1928d1n298dn18d9n219d8n18n118219d8n21e12903e21kj9012j9301j2391023j209d12dn1928d1n298dn18d9n219d8n18n118219d8n21e12903e21kj9012j9301j2391023j209d12dn1928d1n298dn18d9n219d8n18n118219d8n21e12903e21kj9012j9301j2391023j209d12dn1928d1n298dn18d9n219d8n18n118219d8n21e12903e21kj9012j9301j2391023j209'
In [2]: df
Out[2]: 
                                                 url
0  d12dn1928d1n298dn18d9n219d8n18n118219d8n21e129...

In [3]: df.to_html()
Out[3]: u'<table border="1" class="dataframe">\n  <thead>\n    <tr style="text-align: right;">\n      <th></th>\n      <th>url</th>\n    </tr>\n  </thead>\n  <tbody>\n    <tr>\n      <th>0</th>\n      <td>d12dn1928d1n298dn18d9n219d8n18n118219d8n21e129...</td>\n    </tr>\n  </tbody>\n</table>'
```

even in the html output (where it is obvious that it won't fit the screen width), the column value is truncated. How can I force `pandas` to not truncate, both with and without html?

Comment: Isn't this a dupe of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26277757/pandas-to-html-truncates-string-contents/26301947#26301947?

Comment: @EdChum for the non-html part, I guess. However, I'm also partly asking for the logic behind it.. why is it that with html tables, where column length shouldn't matter anyways, values are still truncated?

Comment: Well it also does this for `to_string` as to why I can think it's just a convention so your terminal doesn't bork on trying to display very wide data and lots of rows, the underlying data is not affected.

Answer (score 33):

You can turn off the truncating display option with:

```
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)
```

or before Pandas 1.0,

```
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', -1)
```

Comment: "FutureWarning: Passing a negative integer is deprecated in version 1.0 and will not be supported in future version. Instead, use None to not limit the column width."
Better to use None instead of -1

Answer (score 2):

As an update, instead of

```
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', -1)
```

you should now use

```
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)
```