# Get pandas to print the complete string

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with two columns - one for id and other for the corresponding title. I am subsetting the dataframe for a few project ids and displaying the resulting dataframe. On doing so, the project id gets displayed fine but the corresponding title gets truncated and end with `...` after a few characters, How do I get pandas to display the full text in the title column?

Comment: check `display.max_colwidth` in [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/options.html#frequently-used-options) (`In [44]:`)

Comment: @EdChum not exactly I think. That issue was when the OP had multiple columns and pandas decided to omit a few of them while printing. In my case there's only two columns both of which are getting printed but one gets truncated

Comment: then this is more appropriate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26277757/pandas-to-html-truncates-string-contents/26301947#26301947

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `display.max_colwidth`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1,'aaa'],
                            [2, 'long string long string long string long string long string']]), columns=['id','title'])
```

```
print (df)
  id                                              title
0  1                                                aaa
1  2  long string long string long string long strin...

#temporaly display long text
with pd.option_context('display.max_colwidth', 100):
    print (df)
  id                                                        title
0  1                                                          aaa
1  2  long string long string long string long string long string
```

[Documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/options.html#frequently-used-options)