# Get the string from pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas

I have a tsv file as follows.

```
id    ingredients    recipe
code1  egg, butter   beat eggs. add unsalted butter add coffee and sugar and mix add coffee and sugar and mix add coffee and sugar and mix add coffee and sugar and mix
code2  tim tam, butter  beat tim tam. add butter beat eggs. add unsalted butter beat eggs. add unsalted butter beat eggs. add unsalted butter beat eggs. add unsalted butter beat eggs. add unsalted butter beat eggs. add unsalted butter beat eggs. add unsalted butter beat eggs. add unsalted butter beat eggs. add unsalted butter beat eggs. add unsalted butter beat eggs. add unsalted butter
```

I want to get the strings from the tsv file using the `ingredients` and `recipe` columns.

```
# Reads tab-separated data, minus the column and index headers
data1 = pd.read_csv(f1, sep='\t', index_col=0)
data1 = data1.to_string(header=False, index=False)
```

However, I get only the few words in it and the remaining are truncated as `...` in `data1`.

Please let me know how to fix this?

Comment: I think you need [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26277757/2901002)

Comment: Yes, looks like more of a Jupyter display issue than a data issue.