# print data_frame.head gives output not as a nice table

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data set taken from kaggle, and I want to get the result shown here

[image]

So, I took that code, changed it a bit and what I ran is this:

```
# get titanic & test csv files as a DataFrame
titanic_df = pd.read_csv("./input/train.csv")
test_df    = pd.read_csv("./input/test.csv")

# preview the data
print titanic_df.head()
```

This works, as it outputs the right data, but not as neatly as in the tutorial... Can I make it right?

Here is my output (Python 2, Spyder):

[image]

Comment: The output you see is the output from ipython in jupyter as a web page, it looks like you're seeing the text output which is different as it's console based. Basically what you want is this: https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/notebook/notebook.html#htmlnotebook

Comment: Shouldn't the console at least print it in one line (not using the '\')?

Comment: No, the default pandas options limits the max width of the output, it's decided to wrap around as it exceeds the limits. See [pd.set_option](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.set_option.html) in particular the `display.` params You can increase the `'max_colwidth'` and `'line_width'` params to not wrap it

Comment: Are you sure you are using Spyder? Spyder should have a nice interface, unlike your picture.

Comment: @EdChum Thanks! that did it. Want to add it as an answer, or should I?

Comment: Well if all you wanted was to not wrap the content then [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26277757/pandas-to-html-truncates-string-contents) could be considered a dupe or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11707586/python-pandas-how-to-widen-output-display-to-see-more-columns)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using Jupyter notebook if you have not used it before. In ipython console, it will wrap the text and show it in multiple lines. In kaggle, what you are seeing is itself a jupyter notebook.