# pandas abbreviates dictionary in cell

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, html-table

I have a rather complex nested dictionary that is quite nicely printed as html using pandas.

However there is a dictionary as one of the values which is printed in a cell like that:

[image]

pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', -1) is set, so this should not be the problem.

This is the code that creates the problem:

```
def createTablesFromDict(modelDict, resultNumber, groupName, filenameList):
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', -1)

array=[]
i=0
for value in modelDict.values():
    array.append(list(value.values()))
    temp = array[i][0]
    # header = dictVal
    # This is needed to be able to reorder the table column values.
    # At least I did not find another way...
    array[i][0] = array[i][3]
    array[i][3] = array[i][2]
    array[i][2] = array[i][1]
    array[i][1] = array[i][4]
    array[i][4] = array[i][5]
    array[i][5] = array[i][6]
    array[i][6] = temp
    i += 1

df = pd.DataFrame(array, index=modelDict.keys(), columns=['Against M & S', 'W10 Support', 'BIOS Version', 'Newest BIOS', 'Computers', 'Mapped Category', 'Vendor'])

cols = list(df.columns.values)
logger.debug("Column values: {0}".format(cols))
df = df.fillna("")
fileName = "Result{0}_{1}.html".format(resultNumber, groupName)
filenameList.append(fileName)
df.to_html(fileName)
```

The function is called createTablesFromDict(modelDict, count)

modelDict looks somewhat like this:

```
dictionary = {
'HexaPlex x50': {
    'Vendor': 'Dell  Inc.',
    'BIOS Version': '12.72.9',
    'Newest BIOS': '12.73.9',
    'Against M & S': 'Yes',
    'W10 Support': 'Yes',
    'Computers': {
        'someName001': '12.72.9',
        'someName002': '12.73.9',
        'someName003': '12.73.9'
    },
    'Mapped Category': ['SomeOtherCategory']
},
...
```

}

Does anyone know how to make the entire dictionary show up?

Thank you in advance for even reading.

Comment: What if you set `max_columns` for example to a gigantic number? Does this changes the rendering?

Comment: Is this issue specific to you printing as html (wasn't clear from title of question)? I tried to generate your error, but my code worked.:
`import pandas as pd 
a = really_long_nested_json...
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', -1)
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': a}, index=[0])
df`

Comment: In fact can you show us how you get the error? Even if I print df.to_html() I get the whole JSON

Comment: Added the code to the question