# Pandas Dataframes.to_csv truncates long values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

**Problem:** I'm trying to store big datasets using Pandas dataframes in python. My trouble is that when I try to save it to csv, chunks of my data is being trunctated, as such:

> e+12
>
> **and**
>
> [value1 value2 value3 **. . .** value1853 value1854]

**Explanation:**
I need to store lots of data into single cells, and some of the values I need to store are Long (time) values and I created a short script to display the errors I'm getting:

```
dframe = pd.DataFrame()
arr = np.array([])
for x in range(1234567891230,1234567892230):
    arr = np.append(arr,x)
dframe['elements'] = [arr]
print(dframe['elements'][0][999])   # prints correct values, eg. 1234567892229.0
dframe.to_csv('temp.csv', index=False)
```

In the example above stored values appears *as below* for the first 1000 values (123456789**1230** to 123456789**2230**)

> 1.23456789e+12

Which completely ignores the four *least significant* characters. If you extend the list to 1001 values even more gets truncated:

```
dframe = pd.DataFrame()
arr = np.array([])
for x in range(1234567891230,1234567892231):
    arr = np.append(arr,x)
dframe['elements'] = [arr]
print(dframe['elements'][0][999])   # still prints correct values, eg. 1234567892229.0
dframe.to_csv('temp.csv', index=False)
```

And the full csv file finally looks like this:

> elements
>
> "[1.23456789e+12 1.23456789e+12 1.23456789e+12 ... 1.23456789e+12
> 1.23456789e+12 1.23456789e+12]"

Which has removed almost all of the 1000 elements and replaced them by **...** .

Does anyone know any workaround for these problems or how to solve them?

This is not a problem of truncation simply for display (such as [Pandas to_html() truncates string contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26277757/pandas-to-html-truncates-string-contents)) but actually corrupts the data stored to csv.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Changing the data type as @Jacob Tomlinson said solves one problem, looking into numpys array2string solved the other.

Adding `np.set_printoptions(threshold=np.nan)` stops to_csv from truncating the output strings.

```
dframe = pd.DataFrame()
arr = np.array([])
for x in range(1234567891230,1234567892230):
    arr = np.append(arr,x)
dframe['elements'] = [arr.astype('uint64')]
print(dframe['elements'][0][999])   # prints correct values, eg. 1234567892229.0

np.set_printoptions(threshold=np.nan)
dframe.to_csv('temp.csv', index=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the `dtype` of your numpy array to an integer.

```
dframe = pd.DataFrame()
arr = np.array([], dtype='int16')
for x in range(1234567891230,1234567892230):
    arr = np.append(arr,x)
dframe['elements'] = [arr]
print(dframe['elements'][0][999])   # prints correct values, eg. 1234567892229.0
dframe.to_csv('temp.csv', index=False)
```

Elements

```
"[1234567891230 1234567891231 1234567891232 ... 1234567891233 1234567891234]"
```

Answer (score 0):

So , replicating your code on my machine, I see the rounding, but not the truncation of the list.

I do not know the best solution but here are some suggestions

Do you need the file on drive to he human readable? 
Do what system will read it later?

- if the file will just go into another python step, consider using pickle instead
- consider turning your list into a string, you have full control over the string (e.g. number of explicit decimal places for each value). If you keep the list structure intact internally, but just wrap it in `""` you can easily unpack it with just about any tool out there