# Explode column of arrays when saving dataframe to csv without dots

Tags: arrays, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe which contains a column 'sample' with arrays:[image]

When saving this a csv using to_csv, it prints literal '...' as follows:

[image]

How do I save the dataframe to a CSV where the arrays are expanded to a simple CSV, printing the entire contents of arrays without the '...'s?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53316471/pandas-dataframes-to-csv-truncates-long-values

Comment: Close, but it breaks the array with newlines when printing to csv, so it's still not in a usable state. I need it to be saved such that it can be re-read as a CSV by Pandas with no changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting the array to string and replacing the newline chars is working for me.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'sample':[np.array(range(99999, 99999 + 1000))]})

df['sample'] = df['sample'].apply(lambda x: str(x).replace('\n', ''))

df.to_csv('sample.csv', index=False)
```

If you want to re-read the .csv and get your array back, you can use literal_eval. The first replace is to get rid of the extra space preceding the array values.

```
from ast import literal_eval
new_df = pd.read_csv('sample.csv')
new_df['array_col'] = new_df['sample'].apply(lambda x: np.array(literal_eval(x.replace('[ ', '[').replace(' ', ','))))



print(new_df.loc[0, 'array_col'][0:10])
```

Output:

```
array([ 99999, 100000, 100001, 100002, 100003, 100004, 100005, 100006,
       100007, 100008])
```