# how to read excel file without omit word?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, parsing

I'm trying to ready excel using `pandas.ExcelFile`. but for some excel which put all content into one cell, the result from pandas will omit some word. how to read them completely?Thanks.

[excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5n5p.png)

[result from pandas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DeVN4.png)

this is the code I use:

```
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    xl = pd.ExcelFile(filePath)

    for sheet in xl.sheet_names:
        df_tmp = xl.parse(sheet,header=None,convert_float=False)
        df = df.append(df_tmp, ignore_index=True,sort=False)
        print(df)
```

The input is:
`.xlsx` file, all string is in same cell

```
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC
```

output is

```
                                                   0
0  AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA...
```

Comment: could be good if you a sample of your code, including your input and the output you expect.

Comment: @Sora I have add the code. the input is in the first picture, output is in the second picture. I want to show all words in first picture

Comment: try to print the length of string in your dataframe and match it with excel string i m sure your string is too long to show so dataframe shows you like this

Comment: @Tserenjamts yes, that's true, I find the problem happen from `df.to_html()` this function will omit string

Comment: thank you guys, I found the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26277757/pandas-to-html-truncates-string-contents

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try setting the column width to maximum to avoid truncating the value:

```py
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', -1)
```

I think the issue is not that pandas is not reading the whole cell, it's that the display is truncated.

Answer (score 0):

It is editors problem it is not showing full string but you can access that full word try it.

Comment: how to access ? @Dhaval Rank