# How can I force python to import independent copies of modules' dependencies?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, global-variables

I came across the issue where `pandas.DataFrame.to_html()` is dependent on global state, as cited in [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26277757/pandas-to-html-truncates-string-contents)) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25070758/writing-full-contents-of-pandas-dataframe-to-html-table).  The solutions to those questions were kind of hacky, either modifying the global property and then reverting it, or storing the contents of the DataFrame elsewhere and re-inserting them into the html after conversion.  Moreover, the questions hinted at a more general question: is it possible to load modules and their dependencies in isolation from each other?

There's an MWE below.  When `main.py` is run, it imports `mod1`, which sets the pandas property.  `mod2` is imported next, which recognizes that `pandas` has already been loaded.  It then uses that instantiation of pandas and resets the property.  As a result, when `main.py` later calls `mod1`'s functions, `mod1` sees the property as `mod2` has left it.  This means that `mod1.bar()`, which relies on `pandas.to_html()`, behaves as `mod2` proscribes.  We can check in `main.py` that `mod1.base.pd is mod2.base.pd` (returns True).

Can I specify in `mod1` that I want to import a clean copy of `base` (and it's dependency, `pandas`) so that `mod1.base.pd is not mod2.base.pd`?  Nothing I see in `importlib` allows this.  [`sys.modules`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.modules) alludes to some sort of arcane trickery, but not sure whether that covers this case:

> This [sys.modules] can be manipulated to force reloading of modules and other tricks.

If it's not possible to do so, what's the stylistically correct way of handling the situation?  Moving the global assignment/ `set_option` into each function (`bar()` and `baz()`) would work, but it seems tedious and error-prone if there are a variety of functions that depend on `to_html()` and thus the global state.  I could wrap `DataFrame.to_html(*args)` into a new function `df_to_html(df, temporary_state, *args)` that handles setting and resetting the module option and simply call this function instead of `to_html()`, but again would be tedious if there were more functions that depended on that option.

#### base.py

```
import pandas as pd

def foo():
    return pd.DataFrame([["Looooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong","a"],
                         ["b","Texxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxt"]], 
    columns=['A','B'])
```

#### mod1.py

```
import base

base.pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth',8)

def bar():
    return base.foo().loc[:,['A']].to_html()
```

#### mod2.py

```
import base

base.pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth',5)

def baz():
    return base.foo().loc[:,['B']].to_html()
```

#### main.py

```
import mod1
import mod2

def qux():
    while input():
        print(mod1.bar())
        print(mod2.baz())

if __name__=='__main__':
    qux()
```

#### Output

```
<table border="1" class="dataframe">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: right;">
      <th></th>
      <th>A</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>0</th>
      <td>L...</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>1</th>
      <td>b</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table border="1" class="dataframe">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: right;">
      <th></th>
      <th>B</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>0</th>
      <td>a</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>1</th>
      <td>T...</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Why not have the `bar()` and `baz()` functions set the option just before they call `to_html()`? That surely must be cheaper than loading a separate copy of `pandas` (which seems problematic to get exactly right, in addition to being expensive in terms of memory and cpu).

Comment: @cco I could.  But mine is a contrived, minimal example - there could be many functions that depend on an imported module's global state, and sniping each one seems error prone and maybe not the best style.

Comment: The problem with forcing separate module instances is that you'd need to remove all dependencies from `sys.modules` down to the level where the modules have no global state (if such a level exists).  To me, this seems more error prone (and again, expensive) than setting the global state as needed just-in-time.  Global state is evil exactly because it causes this sort of ugly code; you're left with ugly, brittle code either way.

Answer (score 0):

I have since learned the trickery I mentioned in the question, and yes, this is possible.  You need to make `mod1.py` and `mod2.py` clear out sys.modules of anything that could cache the global variable.  In `mod1.py` and `mod2.py`, add the following text before `import base`:

```
[sys.modules.pop(key) for key in sys.modules.keys() if 'pandas' in key]
try:
    sys.modules.pop('base')
except KeyError:
    pass
```

Then, `main.py`'s `mod1` and `mod2` have different versions of `base.pandas`, which you can verify by adding into `main.py`:

```
print(mod1.base.pandas is mod2.base.pandas)
```

If `mod1` and `mod2` were shipped to you oblibious that their global state change might conflict, you can do something similar with `sys.modules` in `main.py`.  However, that global state is cached in every module that imports `pandas` or a module that imports `pandas`, which is now `mod1`, `mod2`, `base`, and `pandas` and its subpackages/modules.